# Getting Http error 500 while uploading laravel 5 project from local to subdomain on live server

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, server, localhost

I created a laravel project on my local server. It is working fine on local server but it is showing http error 500 on live server.I also move files from public folder to root of the project.

here is my .htacces code

```
         <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
           <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
            Options -MultiViews
          </IfModule>

          RewriteEngine On
          Options -Indexes
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^
          RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L]

          # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
          RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

          # Handle Front Controller...
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
          RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


          # Handle Authorization Header
          RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
          RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
       </IfModule>
```

Comment: check out apache logs.. that's internal server error

Comment: Turn on debug to see what is behind 500 error

Answer (score 0):

run below commands to give directory permissions

```
sudo chmod 755 -R laravel-blog-name   //laravel-blog-name i.e. you project folder name
chmod -R o+w laravel-blog-name/storage
```

Comment: hey thanx for responding.. i already set the permission to 777

Comment: what is the permission of index.php within /public_html

Answer (score 0):

finally i found the reason for error.its because of the server configuration . laravel 5 need php 5.5. version